# Trusted web activity Unable to start activity ComponentInfo Service Intent must be explicit: Intent

Tags: java, android, trusted-web-activity

I have integrated Trusted Web Activity in my Android App when launching TwalauncherActivity as main Activity, App is not opening, it's stopping suddenly & closing automatically.

I have followed [this](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/tree/master/svgomg) link to add Trusted web Activity.

**Logcat:-**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.therightdoctors.cathlab, PID: 2906
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.therightdoctors.cathlab/com.therightdoctors.cathlab.TwaLauncherActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService }
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService }
```

TwaLauncherActivity.java:-

```
package com.therightdoctors.dpmpatient;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.customtabs.CustomTabsIntent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class TwaLauncherActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements TwaSessionHelper.TwaSessionCallback {

    private static final String TWA_ORIGIN = "https://dpmp.therightdoctors.com";
    private static final String TARGET_URL = TWA_ORIGIN;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_twa_launcher);

        Uri originUri = Uri.parse(TWA_ORIGIN);
        TwaSessionHelper twaSessionHelper = TwaSessionHelper.getInstance();
        twaSessionHelper.setTwaSessionCallback(this);
        twaSessionHelper.bindService(this, originUri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        TwaSessionHelper twaSessionHelper = TwaSessionHelper.getInstance();
        twaSessionHelper.setTwaSessionCallback(null);
    }

    public void openTwa() {
        TwaSessionHelper twaSessionHelper = TwaSessionHelper.getInstance();

        // Set an empty transition from TwaLauncherActivity to the TWA splash screen.
        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = twaSessionHelper.createIntentBuilder()
                .setStartAnimations(this, 0, 0)
                .build();

        Uri openUri = Uri.parse(TARGET_URL);
        twaSessionHelper.openTwa(this, customTabsIntent, openUri);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTwaSessionReady() {
        openTwa();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTwaSessionDestroyed() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTwaOpened() {
        finishAndRemoveTask();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you defined the activity in AndroidManifest.xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

The linked demo is outdated (the link is currently broken too, as the demo was moved [here](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/svgomg-twa))

This is the current code for the update [LauncherActivity](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client/blob/master/customtabs/src/android/support/customtabs/trusted/LauncherActivity.java), inside the Support Library.

The latest version of the Support Library supporting TWAs is being hosted in [JitPack](https://jitpack.io/#GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client) temporarily.

It will be merged into the official support library in the near future.